# How to sign JWT token

Tags: .net, jwt, cryptography

I am trying to sign a `JWT` token but it is getting invalid signature error when decoded in `jwt.io`

```
var path = "C:\\temp\\cert.p12";
var cert = new X509Certificate2(path);
var privateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(privateKey), 
SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
{
    CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory { CacheSignatureProviders = false}
};
var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            audience: "xxxx",
            issuer: "xxxx",
            claims: new Claim[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Typ, "user"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "xxxx"),
            },

            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
            signingCredentials: signingCredentials
        );
string token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
```

I tried to validate the token for any problem with signing but did not get exception:

```
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(privateKey),
    CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory()
    {
        CacheSignatureProviders = false
    }
};

try
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedSecurityToken);
    validatedSecurityToken.Dump();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.ToString().Dump();
}
```

This token has invalid signature when decoded in `jwt.io`
Could anyone please suggest how to fix the problem?

Comment: You probably did not paste the public key into the public key field in the right column. Without knowing the public key, the signature can't be verified.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But I am novice and wondering if I can get the public key in this way: `Convert.ToBase64String(cert.GetRSAPublicKey().ExportRSAPublicKey())` I pasted this in the public key box in the right side but still could not get rid of the error. Any thoughts?